# Weird behavior of border-radius

Tags: html, css

I learned we can make also make elliptical border-radius by using this syntax.

```
border-radius: horizontal radius / vertical radius
```

First, I tried `border-radius: 10px 20px/10px`, which worked.

Then, I tried `border-radius: 20px/10px 10px/10px`, It didn't worked, Chrome Developer Tool highlighted it as wrong.

Confused and Frustrated, I went to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius?v=example), and returned more confused.

It shows something like this `border-radius: 10px 5% / 20px 25em 30px 35em`, Isn't it weird? while they mentioned in comments that values belongs to `/* (first radius values) / top-left | top-right | bottom-right | bottom-left */` , but what is `first radius values`.

More I looked into it, more confusing it seems. I know I am missing something, but don't know what!

Answer (score 6):

Look at it in full, you have:

```
border-radius: TLH TRH BRH BLH / TLV TRV BRV BLV;
```

Where
T/B are Top/Bottom,
L/R are Left/Right, and
H/V are Horizontal/Vertical

If you don't have the "/ vertical size", they default to copy the horizontal sizes (so circular corners). If you don't have 4 sizes, it repeats the values you've given.

Once you have the basic structure down, you can experiment with values and see what happens. This is a great way to learn what things do :)

Comment: This post [css-shorthand-clockwise](http://www.vcarrer.com/2010/01/css-shorthand-clockwise-rule.html) can help you to understand css shorthand declaration.